# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in reactjs project \

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

**HomeScreen
Error on line /frontend/src/screens/HomeScreen.js:28**

I want to perform actions on the state of my HomeScreen Page using redux. The data is provided from the api (array of items) then it is rendered on the screen. After All this it shows website it says the above error.

**productReducer.js**

```
import { 
PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,

PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,


} from '../constants/productConstants'

export const productListReducers=(state= { products:[] },action)=>{
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return { loading:true, products:[]}

        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {loading:false, products:action.payload.products}

        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return {loading:false,error:action.payload}

        default:
            return state
    }

}
```

**productAction.js**

```
import { axios } from 'axios'
import { 
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,

    PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL 
} from '../constants/productConstants'

export const listProducts=()=>async(dispatch)=>{ 
    try
    {
        dispatch({type:PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST})
        const { data }= await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/')
        dispatch({
            type:PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
            payload:data
        })
    }
    catch(error){
        dispatch({
            type:PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
            payload:error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message: error.message,
        })
    }

}
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Product from '../components/Product'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions'

function HomeScreen() {
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const productList=useSelector(state=>state.productList)
    const { error, loading, products}=productList
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        
         dispatch(listProducts())  
    },[dispatch])
   
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Latest Products</h1> 
            {loading ? <Loader /> 
                : error ?  <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message> 
                : 
                (
                    <Row>
                        {products.map(product=>(
                            <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                                <Product product={product}/>
                            </Col>
                        ))}
                    </Row>
                )
                
            }          
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

**productConstant.js**

```
export const PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST='PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST'
export const PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS='PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS'
export const PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL='PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL'
```

Comment: For `const { data }= await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/')` here does `data` have a `products` property? It seems you assume it does in the reducer for `PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS ` when accessing the payload `action.payload.products`. Can you update your question in include the `data` value?

Comment: What do the redux devtools say?

Answer (score 0):

```
  {products?.length && products.map(product=>(
      <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
         <Product product={product}/>
      </Col>
   ))}
```

Comment: please check it and tell me what happened

Comment: And what if `products` is `{ length: 2 }`, this code will still fail. This answer doesn't address the issue really.

Comment: yes, I know but I wanted to know what is wrong?

Comment: Do you mean like a comment asking for clarification?